# OSX best performance remote desktop?

Tags: macos, performance, desktop, remote

I am new to osx.

I began using OSX Mountain Lion few days ago and now
finding out best performance remote desktop solution.

I only have bandwidth around 1.5 MBytes per second.
I tried two solutions you may know. TeamViewer and real vnc,  are too slow.

I uses Radmin on windows system. It's amazingly fast and fastest solution on the
 windows platform as far as I know.

Then, What's the fastest remote desktop solution on the Mac platform?

I want to remotely connect from windows(client)  to OSX(server)  for doing job related working

1. From windows to osx.
2. Fast, fast, fast. (NOT losing graphic quality)
3. Good graphic quality.
4. NOT Web based.

I just wanna connect my Mac from windows 
and good graphic quality(16bit would be fine) /performance(like Radmin does)

If you know any good solution meet the requirements, please tell me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently, I'm using AnyDesk. It's relatively a newborn baby.

It means neither feature complete nor stable yet.
But I'm satisfied with it and looks promising

Answer (score 1):

Are you on the same network as the Mac, or is this over the internet? Simply put, the further you are away from the Mac, the larger the resolution of the display you want to push, and the higher the bit-depth of the color you wish to display, the lower the frame rate will be.

I've used the free version of LogMeIn and had good success, especially when I turn the resolution down and switch to grayscale. I've got about half of your 1.5 Mbps to work with. Perhaps you can run in a limited color setup and do okay. LogMeIn has a stand-alone binary on the Mac, I don't know if they offer the same binary on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

After spending [too much] time on this, trying xrdp, various VNC servers, Screen Sharing, I found that [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/) is really easy to use and very performant, so I am sticking with that. Clients and servers are available for Linux, Windows, and Mac.